How do I detect three levels of Cisco configuration
I have this IOS-XR configuration:
router bgp 7
  bgp router-id 10.0.0.7
  address-family ipv4 unicast
  !
  neighbor 10.0.0.70
    remote-as 7
    update-source Loopback0
    route-policy MANGLE_IN in
    route-policy MANGLE_OUT out
      next-hop-self
  !
  neighbor 192.168.1.254
    remote-as 9
    route-policy EBGP_IN in
    route-policy EBGP_OUT out

I need to see if a neighbor is configured with next-hop-self.
I can use this to get the route-policy or remote-as, but how do I check whether the neighbor is configured with next-hop-self?
I'm using this python code:
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse

config = CiscoConfParse('config.txt')
result = config.find_parents_w_child('neighbor 10.0.0.70', 'next-hop-self')
print(result)

This prints an empty list: [], but I expected to see ['      next-hop-self']

This will do what you want, but you need ciscoconfparse2 and find_child_objects():
from ciscoconfparse2 import CiscoConfParse

config = CiscoConfParse('config.txt')
result = config.find_child_objects(['router bgp',
                                    'neighbor 10.0.0.70',
                                    'route-policy',
                                    'next-hop-self'])[0]
print(str(result))

BTW, next-hop-self is not a direct child of neighbor 10.0.0.70, but that was not the most basic problem you have.
